# HttpPostedFileBase return NULL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Help `HttpPostedFileBase` returns `NULL`, I have already tried several things and I have searched in several forums but it works.

This is my code

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("NuevoProveedor", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <center>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="btnFile" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
        </form>
    </center>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NuevoProveedor(HttpPostedFileBase file, SubirArchivoModelo model)
{
        SubirArchivoModelo modelo = new SubirArchivoModelo();

        if (file != null)
        {
            string Ruta = file.FileName;
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.error = "No se pudo generar la carpeta, comunicate con Soporte Tecnico";
            return View("UsuarioNuevo");
        }
 }
```

Comment: why you have put 2 nested forms, just outside one is enough.

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload file and save its url in the database table like this:

**View:**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("NuevoProveedor", "Account",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    ...
    <div class="editor-field">
         <input type="file" id="btnFile" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
    </div>
    ...
}
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NuevoProveedor(SubirArchivoModelo model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                model.FileLocation = Path.Combine(
                    Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(model.FileLocation);
            }
            //db.TableEntity.Add(model);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    return View("UsuarioNuevo");
}
```