# ASP.NET MVC : capture result of download prompt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, actionlink, actionresult, html.actionlink

I have a bit of code that makes a file available and prompts user to `open/download/cancel`. I would like to take an action **if the file is opened or downloaded**, but **not if canceled**.

This is the download line, from the controller :

```
return File(fileAsBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

I guess my question is, how do I capture a return value from this action? Would I see the result in the controller or in the view that calls it?

I'm a struggling newbie. Don't assume foundational knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry this isn't possible, the response is sent to the client and the client doesn't have to reply saying what it did with it... You can probably use Javascript with an AJAX request instead to capture the result, but this be browser dependent and there ins't a universal solution

Comment: Thanks marc_s.  I'll take this as an answer.  For the moment, I don't think I want to get into client-side code for this.  I'll just "assume" they took the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(string SubmitButton, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (SubmitButton == "Cancel")
        {
            //redirect to a cancel page
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //put a breakpoint in this metho to interogate file, 
        //the file you are going to save to db or do something with

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Tut115()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Your view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut115</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload",
        "Home",
        FormMethod.Post,
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Cancel" />
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Upload" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks kblau.  I'm serving the file(s) for client download, not upload.  Trying to capture client's action when they select Open/Save/Cancel in their browser...

Comment: You can research download attachment.  My download attachment code ends with this:    Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myFileName + ".csv");
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();